# Need the images to be vertical-align middle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, carousel

I am trying to make the thumbnails in the carousel "vertically aligned in middle" by default. I know there are lot of post on stackflow about the issue and suggested to use :

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

along with

```
 display:inline-block;
```

But the li elements not taking any effect. I don't have any float item either. Can someone please suggest me anything?

Link to jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ashish_ifb/exfmhk1a/4/

Comment: Please reduce your jsfiddle example to only the minimum necessary amount of code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Try `display:table` for the ul and `table-cell` for the li's

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exfmhk1a/6/

**Solution 2**

Use `position:relative; top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%);` for the `img`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exfmhk1a/10/

Comment: and then apply vertical align : middle to table-cell

Comment: Well, it does work. Thanks for the suggestion. But I have more than 3 image in the carousel and I want to show only 3 at a time. The whole thing (with javascript) is working absolute fine, except the vertical alignment. If I use table and table cell, it force my all images to show up at once.

Comment: I've added a solution 2. Please check that out.

Answer (score 0):

***Easy peasy japanesey***, just modify this `img` selector to:

```
   .maxcarousel__inner ul li img {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exfmhk1a/8/)**